# Loop through every value of string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I get form db field (`organisations.paths`)the following strings:

> /1/2/3/4

Each number is the id of organisation's name from this db table:

```
+----+-------------+----------+----------+----------------------+
| id | frameworkid |   path   | parentid |       fullname       |
+----+-------------+----------+----------+----------------------+
|  1 |           1 | /1       |        0 | NYC University       |
|  2 |           1 | /2       |        0 | Board of directors   |
|  3 |           1 | /1/2/3   |        1 | Math faculty         |
|  4 |           1 | /1/2/3/4 |        3 | Statistic department |
|  5 |           1 | /1/2/3/5 |        2 | Linguist  department |
+----+-------------+----------+----------+----------------------+
```

Then I have the `description table` for each organisation:

```
+----+----------+---------+----------------+
| id |   data   | fieldid | organisationid |
+----+----------+---------+----------------+
|  1 | HQ       |       1 |              1 |
|  2 | advisory |       1 |              2 |
|  3 | advisory |       1 |              3 |
|  4 | bottom   |       1 |              4 |
|  5 | advisory |       1 |              5 |
+----+----------+---------+----------------+
```

How to `join` the both description table and main table and loop only through organisations, which have `HQ` or `advisory` in their description? So it becomes:

> NYC University, Board of directors, Math faculty (Statistic department-won't be shown, as it is with description `bottom`)

Comment: use mysql `IN` to query the result

Comment: Just explode your string; connect to your db; fetch the data where the id is in your exploded array; implode the results;

Comment: you need to update your question, its not a clear view what you really want.

Comment: question is updated, should be more clear now

Comment: @StartVader, now check the query and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `explode`, `IN` and `join` Function of PHP and mysql.

```
$var = "/1/2/3/4";

$in = join(" , ", explode("/", ltrim($var, '/')));

$sql = "SELECT `dt`.`fullname` FROM `db_table` dt
        LEFT JOIN `organization` o
        ON `o`.`organisationid` = `dt`.`id`
        WHERE `o`.`id` IN ($in) AND (`o`.`data` = 'HQ' OR `o`.`data` = 'advisory')";
```

Make a loop to get the names and show them as you want.

Comment: I expanded the question, in order to ask it in one question. Also added the name of the field, where the /1/2/3/4 comes from.

Comment: i just notice, okey i will also update my answer as your question say.

Comment: just check and let me know is it okey or not.

Comment: he mention the fixed `path` from the main table. I actually don't know where he got this. But this need to be join with `,` so i did the explode with ltrim the first `/`.